# Replicate encryption algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, delphi, encryption, aes

*(I tried asking this on Cryptography Stack Exchange and they didn't feel it was appropriate there.)*

I'm trying to replicate an algorithm written in Delphi in C#, preferably using the standard .NET libraries. Supposedly the Delphi algorithm passes standard reference tests. It's supposed to be AES/CBC; however, I've been unable to duplicate the results with System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged.

Example of calling it with simple input:

```
function StringToHex(S: string): string;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for i := 1 to Length(S) do
    Result := Result + IntToHex(Ord(S[i]), 2);
end;

var
  PlainText:     AnsiString;
  AES:           TAES;
  Key:           TAESKey256;  // array[0..31] of byte;
  InitialVector: TAESBuffer;  // array[0..15] of byte;
  InputStream:   TStringStream;
  OutputStream:  TStringStream;

begin
  PlainText := 'test';
  FillChar(Key, SizeOf(Key), 1);
  FillChar(InitialVector, SizeOf(InitialVector), 2);

  AES          := TAES.Create;
  InputStream  := TStringStream.Create(PlainText);
  OutputStream := TStringStream.Create('');

  try
    AES.EncryptAESStreamCBC(InputStream, 0, Key, InitialVector, OutputStream);

    Writeln(StringToHex(OutputStream.DataString));
    Readln;
  finally
    InputStream.Free;
    OutputStream.Free;
    AES.Free;
  end;
end.
```

Output:

```
CEE3684F05D02E5A0930CED21F76075A
```

The code appears to have been based on the [Delphi Spring Framework](http://delphi-spring-framework.googlecode.com/svn-history/r287/trunk/Experiments/Cryptography/Spring.Cryptography.AES.pas).

How can I replicate this in .NET?

What I've tried (even switching to bytes to avoid any Unicode issues):

```
public byte[] Encrypt()
{
    using (var algorithm = new AesManaged())
    {
        // Default is CBC
        algorithm.Key = Enumerable.Repeat((byte)0x01, 32).ToArray();
        algorithm.IV = Enumerable.Repeat((byte)0x02, 16).ToArray();

        using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(algorithm.Key, algorithm.IV))
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(stream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(cryptoStream))
                    {
                        writer.Write(new byte[] {0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74});
                    }
                    return stream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This results in different output, though (the first byte is x6D).

Comment: I don't know what exact problem is but you may think of providing a Delphi dll to c# as a quick solution. Do the job in delphi, call it in C#.

Comment: Are you sure that algorithm (instance of AesManaged) has correct blocksize/keysize by default (should be 128/256 correspondingly)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In other task guy mentioned default settings for c#:

```
BlockSize = 128;
Mode = System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.CBC;
Padding = System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.PKCS7
```

In Delphi i can't see any option to change PaddingMode and i guess it padds with zeros.
If it is correct, then you should switch padding in C# to

```
System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.Zeros
```

(sorry, can't check it, it is just assumption).

Update: As shunty mention, it works, just add line:

```
algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
```

Comment: Much as I would like to steal any credit - this is the answer. Just checked it with a quick script in LINQPad and you just need to add "algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;" (No 'e' in it!). Bob's your uncle.

Comment: Confirmed. I just had to add `TrimEnd('\0')` when decrypting. Thank you very, very much!

Comment: @TrueWill You are welcome :) But i think TrimEnd is not 100% safe. If last byte/bytes of _real_ data is 0, then you rid them off together with padding. Probably it is better to use PaddingMode property.

Comment: Agreed - with binary data trimming would not be safe. I'm dealing with textual data; when using PaddingMode.Zeros the decrypted result is padded to length 16 in this case.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the facility by the Spring framework in Delphi my suggestion is to create a Win32 [Library] DLL using Delphi and consume that DLL inside your .NET application. That sounds like a more logical solution than rewriting the code in C#(reinventing the wheel?).

Comment: +1 - I'm considering that. My hope was that the library was doing standard AES (or Rijndael) and that I just wasn't setting up .NET correctly. It would be nice to use standard, well-tested Microsoft libraries.

Comment: The Delphi library's results are repeatable from a tool that I assume isn't using the same library: http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/link/228f72gGd89UfPMaS/. Rewriting the code in C# doesn't really seem like reinventing the wheel here. Rather, it's a matter of finding the way to use the wheel that's already built in to the system.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that TStringStream returns the AnsiString 'test' into exactly 4 bytes?
Multibyte encoding and/or zero-termination will result in another plain-text byte-array than used in the C# code.

Comment: +1 for a really good question; I just verified that InputStream.Bytes is ($74, $65, $73, $74) though.